# What should be ignored when putting the "custom" SugarCRM folder under git version control?

Tags: git, sugarcrm

I have my "custom" folder  in my SugarCRM 6.2 sandbox under git version control.

I'm noticing a lot of changes that I think I don' really need to keep track of.  For instance, I don't think it makes sense to keep track of a copy of every previous def file that seems to occur under the history folders.

I'm wondering what are the best practices for keeping `/custom` folder under version control.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With questions like these and larger projects like SugarCRM, there's usually some community `.gitignore` files to observe. [Check out this one](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/SugarCRM.gitignore), which agrees with you about the history folder and just ignores everything in the `custom/history` folder.

Comment: whoa, that's extactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! That's the nice thing about github - someone usually throws one of these up and it works nicely.